# Symofony building subform

Tags: php, symfony, subform

Im trying to create a special form, first of all I have a form about a professional, and it has experience as a property. I add those values to my form:

```
$builder->add('job_company');
$builder->add('job_position');
```

The problem is that I want to be able to generate multiple experiences, with a button.
I should use the CollectionType of symphony, but I don't know if I need to create another special form for the experience, so when I click on the button I create those inputs with a different name (this name must be different if I want to validate them).

I've tried to use:

```
->add('experiences', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type'   => TextType::class,
        'allow_add'  => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ))
```

But when I try to render it (`{{ form_widget(form.experiences)}}`), I get these error:

> AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalExperience could not be converted to string

I also tried (`{{ form_widget(form.experiences.company)}}`) but I can't get this variable.

How can I do it properly?

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared that you `experiences` subform is `TextType`, therefore

```
{{ form_widget(form.experiences)}}
```

is trying to create a simple `<input/>` field and set its value. The value of input is a simple string while you're providing `AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalExperience` instance. That's why you're getting this error.

You don't want it to be `TextType`. It should be some kind of custom form class like `ExperienceType`.

```
->add('experiences', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type'   => ExperienceType::class,
        'allow_add'  => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ))
```

And you should of course create such form class with fields suitable for your `AppBundle\Entity\ProfessionalExperience` entity